# How to insert symbol in sql database

Tags: mysqli

I am trying to insert into sql database this (Age 70+) but it only entered (Age 70) without (+) my column type is varchar what is the suitable type to include numbers and symbols???

Comment: varchar is just "variable-length text". unless you created your table with a character set that doesn't contain symbols, mysql couldn't care less what you shove into the field. it's all just text. you need to show how/where you get this text and insert it. we can NOT fix code we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my english.
+ this is special symbol, need to use slash. If you use php, you can use function Addslashes() and stripslashes().
you can read about this on site mysql and php dot net.
I hope that i help you.